# CSS locator in Selenium for Python

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-ide

[image]

CSS locator :".header-GlobalAccountFlyout-link.display-block" returns 3 elements in a class. I need to get to the last one -"Create an Account". Does anybody know how to finish writing CSS to get there? Thank You.

Comment: You can read this: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

Using [Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) we don't necessarily need the Class selectors here at all.

You have a few options:

1. If `data-uid` never changes:

   ```
   [data-uid="eRDhfBAS"]
   ```
2. If the `href` link never changes:

   ```
   [href="/account/signup"]
   ```
3. If the `alt` text never changes:

   ```
   [alt="Create an Account"]
   ```
4. If the `data-tl-id` never changes:

   ```
   [data-tl-id="header-GlobalAccountFlyout-flyout-link-1"]
   ```

If there may be other elements with those same attributes and values, simply include your Class selectors as well. For example:

```css
.header-GlobalAccountFlyout-link.display-block[href="/account/signup"]
```

Or you could combine some of the above attribute selectors...

```css
[href="/account/signup"][alt="Create an Account"]
```

Comment: I tried all that in my Firefox CSS locator and it does not work. Do I cut and paste these options or I need to use other syntax?  I also tried : .header-GlobalAccountFlyout-link.display-block[href="/account/signup"]                                 Not working either.